# Python Background change with Python 3 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to change my background image using python but I doesn't work and I can't find why.

here is my code:

```
import ctypes
import os

folder = "C:\\Users\\Nuriddin\\Desktop\\images"
image = "images[0].jpg"
image_path = os.path.join(folder, image)
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, image_path, 0)
```

What is wrong in this code ? (I am sure that I entered the good path)

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.4-x

Comment: @baldr Thanks didn't expect it comes from the version of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `SystemParametersInfoA`, that's the ASCII/byte/char oriented interface; `image_path` should probably be encoded to `bytes` (or you should use `SystemParametersInfoW` for the Unicode/wchar interface).

In Python 3, `str` is a text type that corresponds (in `ctypes`) to the Unicode/wchar interfaces; `bytes` is a binary data type that corresponds to ASCII/char interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

here is the right parameter , how that its gonna help you :

```
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE   = 0x1

lpszImage = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), 'your_image.jpg')

SystemParametersInfo = windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, lpszImage, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE)
```

thanks,
regards .